# Using s3 emulator with private bucket as source for GeoServer image mosaic

Tags: geoserver, s3

I am trying to render image mosaic on GeoServer from s3 emulator used for development.

Example of value set for location attribute defined in database : *http://192.168.180.132:9444/s3/esat/image.tif*

When I set my bucket to public the mosaic is rendered correctly.

Example of my mosaic config:

```
#-Automagically created from GeoTools-                                                                                                    
#Thu Feb 16 18:03:31 GMT 2023                                                                                                             
TimeAttribute=ingestion                                                                                                                   
ExpandToRGB=false                                                                                                                         
TypeName=granule                                                                                                                          
SuggestedFormat=org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat                                                                                    
Name=granule                                                                                                                              
SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.CogImageReaderSpi                                                                    
CogRangeReader=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.HttpRangeReader                                                                    
LevelsNum=3                                                                                                                               
PathType=RELATIVE                                                                                                                         
Heterogeneous=true                                                                                                                        
Caching=false                                                                                                                             
CogUseCache=false                                                                                                                         
HeterogeneousCRS=false                                                                                                                    
LocationAttribute=location                                                                                                                
Levels=1.2002745447393426,1.2002745447393426 2.4022115195960527,2.4027314068327565 
4.8044230391921054,4.805462813665513                   
CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false                                                                                                              
Cog=true                                                                                                                                  
MosaicCRS=HTRS96_Croatia_TM                                                                                                               
CogUser=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE                                                                                                              
CogPassword=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

When I switch my bucket to private, mosaic isn't rendered anymore. Documentation defines that I should set **CogRangeReader** to **it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.cog.S3RangeReader** if bucket is private and authentication is used, but it still won't work when I do that. There is no error in logs, but from layer configuration on GS interface I can see that source tif-s are not recognized because in band definition there is only one and not four of them as it should be. Is this somehow connect with s3 provider?

Does it work only with AWS, is there anyone who had similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going trough source code I found about environment variable **IIO_$ALIAS_AWS_ENDPOINT** which is not exposed in documentation. After I set
**IIO_S3_AWS_ENDPOINT={myendpoint}** and granule location attribute to `s3://bucket/granule.tif` it works properly